# (C++) using a vector as a wrapper in a stack

Tags: c++, vector, stack

EDIT: Original question answered. Relevant issue though, didn't feel like it deemed making a new post. Why am I unable to use the push() and pop() function calls of my stack? Here are the errors:

```
HCTree.cpp:65:16: error: no matching member function for call to 'push'
  encoding.push(0);
  ~~~~~~~~~^~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/stack:197:10: note: 
  candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const stack<int,
  std::vector<int> >', but method is not marked const
void push(value_type&& __v) {c.push_back(_VSTD::move(__v));}
     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/stack:194:10: note: 
  candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const stack<int,
  std::vector<int> >', but method is not marked const
void push(const value_type& __v) {c.push_back(__v);}
     ^
HCTree.cpp:67:16: error: no matching member function for call to 'push'
  encoding.push(1);
  ~~~~~~~~~^~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/stack:197:10: note: 
  candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const stack<int,
  std::vector<int> >', but method is not marked const
void push(value_type&& __v) {c.push_back(_VSTD::move(__v));}
     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/stack:194:10: note: 
  candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const stack<int,
  std::vector<int> >', but method is not marked const
void push(const value_type& __v) {c.push_back(__v);}
     ^
HCTree.cpp:73:16: error: member function 'pop' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const
  stack<int, std::vector<int> >', but function is not marked const
  out.writeBit(encoding.pop());
           ^~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/stack:206:10: note: 
  'pop' declared here
void pop() {c.pop_back();}
     ^
```

the code:

```
void HCTree::encode(byte symbol, BitOutputStream& out) const
{

  HCNode* temp;
  temp = leaves[symbol];//store leaf node containing symbol into temp
  /* traverse to the top of the tree */
  while(temp->p != NULL)
  {
    /* record path we take to parent into a stack */
    if(temp == temp->p->c0)//if temp is the c0 child
      encoding.push(0);
    else//temp is the c1 child
      encoding.push(1);

    temp = temp->p;//move up to temp's parent and repeat
  }

   /* write bits to buffer */
   out.writeBit(encoding.pop());


}
```

Relevant line from HCTree.hpp:

```
    stack<int,std::vector<int>> encoding;
```

Is there something about using a vector that is preventing me from using the push() and pop() function calls?

----Original post----:
I am trying to create a stack that stores ints in C++ using a vector as a wrapper, as is done in the example seen here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/stack/

I need a stack that stores ints, so I have the code:

```
std::vector<int> wrapper;
stack<int,std::vector<int>> encoding (wrapper);
```

and I get the following error:

```
Compiling: compress.cpp -> build/compress.o
In file included from compress.cpp:19:
./HCTree.hpp:35:43: error: unknown type name 'wrapper'
stack<int,std::vector<int>> encoding (wrapper);
```

How can I fix my implementation? I need to create an initially *empty* stack to push 1's and 0's onto as I backtrace a binary tree in order to later pop off to rebuild the path that was taken.

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://ideone.com/AcahGB

Comment: Your error also claims to have at least 19 lines of code, but you've only shown 2...

Comment: You really should post a different question (and accept the answer below if you found it useful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty stack is the default. All you need is:

```
#include <stack>
#include <vector>

std::stack<int, std::vector<int> > encoding;
```

Also, cplusplus.com is not a very good source. It has more ads and fewer editors. Avoid it.

> I need to create an initially empty stack to push 1's and 0's onto as I backtrace a binary tree in order to later pop off to rebuild the path that was taken.

Why not `std::stack< bool, std::vector< bool > >`? Note that `std::vector< bool >` has optimal storage characteristics.

---

### Second question

(Please do not add to questions. Opening new ones is free.)

You cannot change `encoding` inside a member function that is marked `const`, because that context makes data members behave as `const`. There are several solutions:

1. Let the `encode` function not be `const`, since it meaningfully changes the state of the `HCTree` object.
2. Do not make `encoding` a member of `HCTree`. Put it in some other object or require that it be supplied by the user.
3. Declare `encoding` as `mutable`. This doesn't seem appropriate. The state of `mutable` members generally should not be observable, aside from side-effects like improved performance.